# Relacionamento com MongoDB

Tags: ionic, typescript, mongodb, relacionamento

Estou usando o populate para criar relacionamento com mongoDB, no caso eu tenho os clientes e os projeto, sendo os dois pertencentes ao usuário logado, e sendo o projeto pertencente à um cliente, minha dúvida é que para relacionar o cliente com o usuario foi tranquilo, pois não havia outro relacionamento com o cliente, já o projeto que já está relacionado com o cliente eu me perdi um pouco.

Minha Dao do projeto

```
       async getAll(){ 
           return await this._base._model.find().populate('cliente', '_id nome email tel endereco cidade bairro cep');
       }
```

Por já ter o getAll com o relacionamento com o cliente, como poderia fazer para adicionar o usuario, assim como está na DAO do meu cliente. Se eu criar um outro get funcionaria ?

```
Meu model do projeto:

const projetoModel = new schema({
    //nomeCliente: {trim: true, required: true, type: String, index: true},
    //tel: {trim:true, requried: true, type: String},
    //email: {type: String},
    //endereco: {type: String, required: true},
    //bairro: {type: String, required: true},
    //cidade: {type: String, required: true, index: true},
    tituloProjeto: {trim: true, required: true, index: true, type: String },
    descricaoProjeto: {type: String, required: true},
    //cep: {type: String, required: true},
    preco: {type: String},
    foto: {type: Array},
    status: {type: Boolean, default: true},
    data: {type: Date, default: new Date()},
    cliente: {type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Clientes'}

}
```

Dao cliente:

```
 async getAll(){ 
        return await this._base._model.find().populate('usuario', '_id nome email');
    }
```

Comment: Da uma olhada na manual do mongodb sobre relacionamento de collection:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html

Comment: Já consegui brother, Obrigado.